# In Android Studios build.gradle, where do I find the 'project' file?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I just imported build.grade file of the facebook module in android studio and it contain below code:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
}
```

My question is Which file does 'project' point to ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the root of your project you should have a `gradle.properties` file. In there you should see (or can set yourself) these attributes.

```
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=19
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=19
```

If you need to use a version number like 19.0.2 instead of 19, you need to quote the value.

```
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION="19.0.2"
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION="19.0.2"
```